# How to use Woocommerce without CART?

Tags: woocommerce

In Woocommerce, is there a way to work without CART, in single shop page hide quantities and changing ADD TO CART button by GO TO CHECKOUT ?

Answer (score 2):

i also found this

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout');

function redirect_to_checkout() {
    return WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this plugin, I think this should work for you... https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-direct-checkout/

Answer (score -1):

Below is an alternative that will delete the cart button. However, it will also remove the checkout system.

It is useful for creating a products catalog with WooCommerce.

http://chrislema.com/woocommerce-product-page-without-shopping-cart/